# How to display a list of years since a specific year using Twig and Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

With this application I'm building I want the user to be able to look at records from previous years. So if that user has records dating back to 2005, I want to be able to display a list of years since then including that year, for example:

> List of years: 2012 | 2011 | 2010 | 2009 | 2008 | 2007 | 2006 | 2005

I've worked out the SQL to retrieve the oldest record from the database, which is as follows:

```
    // Retrieve Oldest Record
    $minimumyear = $dm->createQuery('
    SELECT min(msu.endDate) as msuMin
    FROM InstructorBundle:MapSubscriptions msu 
    LEFT JOIN InstructorBundle:MapContacts mc WHERE msu.contact = mc.id
    LEFT JOIN InstructorBundle:MapFamilies mf WHERE mc.family = mf.id
    WHERE mf.branch = :centre'
    )->setParameter('centre', $centreid);

    $minyear = $minimumyear->getResult();
```

The problem I have is that now I've got the oldest year, I'm not sure how I can use Twig to display the list I need. I have thought about extending Twig to allow this, but I don't want to go down that avenue for the time being just incase there is a function in Twig that would allow me to do this.

How can I display the list I need using Twig?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just use twig's [date function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/date.html) to get the current year using `"now"` then loop from the minimum year to the current one with a [for loop](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/for.html).

```
{% set minimumYear = 2010 %}

List of years: {{ minimumYear }}
{% for year in (minimumYear+1).."now"|date("Y") %}
    | {{ year }}
{% endfor %}
```

outputs:

> List of years: 2010 | 2011 | 2012 | 2013

.. or to get the current year first

```
{% set minimumYear = 2010 %}
{% set currentYear = "now"|date("Y") %}   

List of years: {{ currentYear }}
{% for year in (currentYear-1)..minimumYear %}
   | {{ year }}
{% endfor %}
```

outputs:

> List of years: 2013 | 2012 | 2011 | 2010

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you very much. For the record, your second example was exactly what I was looking for. However, the list of years range from 2012 to 2010 with your code. Ideal for me.